# Error: Document Upload URL Path Location Change

Tags: 2013, document-library, error, url

I have been experiencing the oddest thing.  I have a excel spreadsheet that has links within the document that are linked to a network drive.  The links work perfectly in the excel spreadsheet until I upload the excel workbook to the SP13 document library. When I upload the workbook to the document library the URL is changed to the document library URL automatically.  Has anyone experienced this issue before?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to set "Update links on save" to false prior to adding your hyperlinks to the Excel spreadsheet.

In Excel 2010:
- uncheck "Update links on save" in Options > General > Web Options > Files tab

In Excel 2013:
- uncheck "Update links on save" in Options > Advanced > Web Options (under "General") > Files tab

After changing the Excel setting, re-create your hyperlinks in the spreadsheet, re-upload to SharePoint, and the links ought to be correct.

Comment: thank you so much for your response.  I will try that now.  Thank you!

Comment: Hope it works for you! Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Your steps were very helpful.  The issue is still happening.  Now I am not sure if this is a SharePoint issue.  There are two other documents within the document library with embedded links to the network within the spreadsheet that are not experiencing the same issue.  I unchecked "update links on save" and recreated the link.  Therefore, if this were a SharePoint issue I am thinking the other two excel workbooks would not work either.  Not sure what the issue maybe.  However, I appreciate all of your help.  Thanks!